How to apply Pohlig Hellman using a very limited set of auxiliary inputs in that case?
So I was reading about Talotti, Paier, and Miculan - ECC’s Achilles’ Heel: Unveiling Weak Keys in Standardized Curves. The underlying idea is to lift the discrete logarithm problem to $\mathrm{prime}−1$ for prime curves or $\mathrm{order}−1$ for binary curves without using auxiliary inputs at all since most elliptic curves only have small factors in that case. But their baby‑step giant‑step variant seems to only work when the private key already lie in a specific subgroup. That is : no indication is made on how to move the key to each underlying order subgroup. And of course, using exponentiations to solve the problem isn’t a reason that allow building an index calculus algorithm…
So this means the work isn’t currently usefull.
If I understand correctly (or maybe I’m wrong), being able to use Pohlig Hellman would require using auxiliary inputs as proposed by Cheon : but in my case, I only have 48 of them over the extension of a pairing friendly curve of large characteristic.

So more a research question than etablished facts.

In Talotti, Paier, and Miculan's paper, the so-called "weak keys" are $(Y=[k]G,k)$ with $k$ of low order in $\mathbb Z_p^*$ where $p$ is the prime order of $G$. The $Y$ of such key pairs is identifiable, and their $k$ is somewhat easier to find than for a random $Y$. But my assessment is that there is demonstrably no point in screening a randomly chosen key to test if it's one of these "weak keys", contrary to what the article suggests. Independently: the question refers to Jung Hee Cheon's Discrete Logarithm Problems with Auxiliary Inputs.

Pohlig-Hellman only applies to the Discrete Logarithm Problem in a composite order group or subgroup. For this reason it's not applicable to solving the DLP for any the of the standard elliptic curve parameters in sec2. The question asks something else, so this is not an answer. It would help if the question detailed it's setup and parameters, and what the 48 auxiliary inputs are.

@fgrieu the paper propose as future reasearch to try to find a way to use those $prime−1$ subgroup for Pohlig Hellman (but without auxilliary inputs). It seems to me using auxillary input is an easier path.
